# Use JavaScript to Inject custom code into the <head> and <body> of a page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a software application that allows the user to add custom code to both the `<head>` tag and `<body>` tag of a webpage that I am dynamically creating. They need to be able to add the following:

`<div>`
`<style>`
`<!-- Comments -->`
`<script>`

I've built the app on ReactJS So I need to insert it with Javascript (to spare the details). IS there a way to add a code block to a page (`<head>` and `<body>`) and then execute the scripts as well as keep all comments and other tags?

I've tried this but it doesn't execute:

```
      document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', customCodeFooter);
```

I've tried this, but it strips non `<script>` tags:

```
  const insertScriptTagToHead = (scriptTag, position) => {
    var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.innerHTML = scriptTag;
    var scripts = wrapper.getElementsByTagName('script');
    for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.innerHTML = scripts[i].innerHTML;
      document.head.appendChild(script);
    }
  }
```

Anhy help appreciated

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't place `<div>` elements in the `<head>` section of an html document. And second, I'm not sure what you expect. But the only things you are actually appending to the `<head>` sections are `<script>` tags. You are creating a `wrapper` element to be a `<div>`, but you are never attaching it anywhere in the DOM.

Comment: I agree on the first point, and I can do some basic validation once this core is up, but one might want script, meta, or style tags in the header. Regardless I would need this functionality for the `<body>` tag insert so i tried to keep it simple for this quesiton. On the second point, the div `wrapper` isn't appended but the code grabs the script tags and appends them 1 by 1, which works, but is just limiting.